# Having trouble with feval and function

Tags: matlab

While I have my function grad as

```
function g = grad(x)
    g = [4*(x(1)-4)^3 ; 2*x(2)-6 ; 16*(x(3)+5)^3];

end
```

Why do i have a error message "Not enough input arguments. Error in grad (line 2) g = [4*(x(1)-4)^3 ; 2*x(2)-6 ; 16*(x(3)+5)^3];" when I try to run the code

```
x = [4;2;-1];
feval(grad,x)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passed as an argument of the feval, the function name should be passed as a string or as a function handle. So:

```
x = [4;2;-1];
feval("grad", x)
```

(Notice the quotation marks around the "grad").

Or:

```
x = [4;2;-1];
feval(@grad, x)
```